# Summing the column values of all the rows in a Dataframe - scala/spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I am new to scala/spark. I am working on a scala/java application on spark, trying to read some data from a hive table and then sum up all the column values for each row. for example consider the following DF:

```
+--------+-+-+-+-+-+-+
| address|a|b|c|d|e|f|
+--------+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|Newyork |1|0|1|0|1|1|
|   LA   |0|1|1|1|0|1|
|Chicago |1|1|0|0|1|1|
+--------+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

I want to sum up all the 1's in all the rows and get the total.i.e. the above dataframe's sum of all the columns should be 12 (since there are 12 number of 1's in all the rows combined)

I tried doing this:

```
var count = 0
DF.foreach( x => {
    count = count + Integer.parseInt(x.getAs[String]("a")) + Integer.parseInt(x.getAs[String]("b")) + Integer.parseInt(x.getAs[String]("c")) + Integer.parseInt(x.getAs[String]("d")) + Integer.parseInt(x.getAs[String]("e")) + Integer.parseInt(x.getAs[String]("f")) 
})
```

When I run the above code, the `count` value is still being `zero`. I think this has something to do with running the application on a cluster. So, declaring a variable and adding to it doesn't work for me as I have to run my application on a cluster. I also tried declaring static variable in a separate java class and adding to it - that gives me the same result.

As far as my knowledge goes, there should be an easy way of achieving this using the inline functions available in spark/scala libraries.

What would be an efficient way of achieving this? Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

***P.S: I am using Spark 1.6.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sum the columns values firstly which gives back a single Row data frame of `sum`s, then you can convert this Row to a Seq and sum the values up:

```
val sum_cols = df.columns.tail.map(x => sum(col(x)))    
df.agg(sum_cols.head, sum_cols.tail: _*).first.toSeq.asInstanceOf[Seq[Long]].sum
// res9: Long = 12
```

---

```
df.agg(sum_cols.head, sum_cols.tail: _*).show
+------+------+------+------+------+------+
|sum(a)|sum(b)|sum(c)|sum(d)|sum(e)|sum(f)|
+------+------+------+------+------+------+
|     2|     2|     2|     1|     2|     3|
+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I only need to select the columns from `a to f`. I don't need the `address` column. How do I exclude it?

Comment: Use `df.columns.tail` to exclude `address` if it is the first column, see the solution above.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've accepted it. But, what if my values in the columns are string? How can I sum them after converting to int?

Comment: If the strings can be casted to Int, you can cast before *sum* like so `import org.apache.spark.sql.types.IntegerType; .map(x => sum(col(x).cast(IntegerType)))`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative approach:

first let's prepare an aggregating function:

```
scala> val f = df.drop("address").columns.map(col).reduce((c1, c2) => c1 + c2)
f: org.apache.spark.sql.Column = (((((a + b) + c) + d) + e) + f)
```

get sum as a DataFrame:

```
scala> df.agg(sum(f).alias("total")).show
+-----+
|total|
+-----+
|   12|
+-----+
```

get sum as a `Long` number:

```
scala> df.agg(sum(f)).first.getLong(0)
res39: Long = 12
```